# How to produce an NSString with format HxHHHHHHHH representing a float value in Objective C, C++, or C?

Tags: c++, objective-c, c, floating-point, hex

Suppose we have

```
float x = 24.0;
```

I want to do the following:

```
// hexRepresentation is of format HxHHHHHHHH 
// where H is a hexadecimal symbol 0-9 or a-f
NSString *hexRepresentation = [self hexadecimalFromFloat:x];
```

Please help me complete the following method:

```
- (NSString *)hexadecimalFromFloat:(float)flt {
    NSString *h;
    /*
        What should I do here to convert the float
        value into its HxHHHHHHHH format? Then what
        should I do to ensure it's converted into a
        proper NSString and assigned to h?
     */
    return h;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rough, untested code:

```
unsigned int *fp = (unsigned int*)&flt;
h = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"0x%08X", *fp];
```

This may or may not be in IEEE-754 notation, etc etc. It also assumes `sizeof(float) == sizeof(int) == 4`

Comment: No, this will round the float to an integer and print out the hex representation of that integer.

Comment: @Adam Rosenfield this is okay - yes, things to the right of the decimal get chopped when you cast to unsigned int, but you can always mul the original float by powers of 16 or 10 and then interpret that post-conversion; of course, there's that nasty 2's compliment to deal with as well, but it was the format I was primarily after... it's a finite world after all

Answer (score 3):

You can get the machine data of a float either by using a union, or by casting a pointer and dereferencing. A union is used when multiple types could be stored in one location, and any of those types can be accessed no matter which was used to set the value.

```
union {
    float f;
    unsigned int i;
} converter;
converter.f = flt;
// converter.i now contains an integer representing the hexadecimal value of flt
h = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"0x%08X",converter.i];
```

If you get the pointer to the float and then cast it to an integer, you get the same effect. This method takes less code, but can be more confusing when you see it.

```
h = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"0x%08X",*((unsigned int *)(&flt))];
```

Just like Yann's answer, the result is the machine's representation of the float, and this code assumes a float and int are both 4 bytes long.